# One more AC equivalence question

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, axiom-of-choice

Is "Every vector space admits a norm" weaker than AC? I know that the statement follows from "Every vector space has a basis", which is equivalent to AC.

Comment: Of course only real/complex vector spaces are of interest here.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326653/do-you-need-the-axiom-of-choice-to-assert-that-every-real-vector-space-has-a-nor is related.