# Example of a basis of $C[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

What are examples of a basis of $C[0,1]$? *(Hamel basis or Schauder basis... related: [What is the difference between a Hamel basis and a Schauder basis?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/630142/))*

Comment: Do you mean as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: The usual one is described [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=5BDX2NNsqR4C&pg=PA185&lpg=PA185&dq=schauder+basis+C[0,1]&source=bl&ots=4dxUI4FxWv&sig=7Zjzp-v_Kv7XzI3zlUv3mkmq0cY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=2ML0UvN0h_jIAauWgMgK&ved=0CGIQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=schauder%20basis%20C[0%2C1]&f=false). Schauder discovered this basis, I believe; it is called *the* Schauder Basis of $C[0,1]$.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198575/explicit-norm-on-mathcalc0-mathbbr-mathbbr

Comment: Do you mean a Hamel basis?

Answer (score 6):

The Faber-Schauder basis of $C[0,1]$, mentioned by David Mitra, consists of the following functions: $f_0\equiv 1$, and after that $$f_{j,k} = (1-2^j|x-k/2^j|)^+,\quad j\ge  0, \quad 1\le k\le 2^j, \ \text{ $k$ is odd}$$ 
Apart from $f_0$, these are essentially antiderivatives of [Rademacher functions](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Rademacher_system), which hints at the reason for their good basis properties. The form a monotone Schauder basis for $C[0,1]$. In contrast, polynomials and trigonometric polynomials fail at this task.

A couple of pictures: functions up to $j=2$

[image: basis]

and up to $j=3$

[image: basis2]

Answer (score 4):

I assume you want Hamel basis.  If you mean Schauder basis (or some other type of basis, like a base for the topology), you should say so.

I cannot write down a Hamel basis for $C[0,1]$.  However, I can write down a linearly independent set of cardinal $\mathfrak{c} = 2^{\aleph_0}$.  For $s \in (0,1)$, let $g_s \in C[0,1]$ be piecewise linear with $g_s(0)=0$, $g_s(1)=0$, $g_s(s) = 1$.  The uncountable set $\{g_s : s \in (0,1) \}$ is linearly independent.